# Batch job failing without any error message other than Job Failed

Tags: batch

I have a batch job running that is failing without any error message apart from Job  Failed.

When I query the AsyncApexJob record corresoponding to the run I get only job 7072400004lqDgo failed in the ExtendedStatus  field.

How can I fix any bug if there is no indication of what the bug is?

Comment: can you provide quote of that full error message

Comment: What kind of operation you are performing in batch class.If it is DML operation,you can use Try catch block and you will be able to see Exception in debug logs.

Comment: The full error is 'job 7072400004lqDgo failed'.

Comment: The dml statements are wrapped in a try catch already. Even if every insert failed the batch job should not fail. There are no errors in the debug log for this batch.

Comment: how many records you are processing. Check if you are getting any timeout error.

Comment: @Tushar, I was suspecting a governor limit excetption, however that would usually be recorded in the AsyncApexJob record and isn't. Do you have another way to check?

Comment: @SeanKemplay yes it will be tracked. Can you post screenshot from apex job page of your batch?

Comment: Hi @Tushar, which page do you mean? Jobs -> Scheduled Jobs or Jobs -> Apex Jobs?

Comment: @SeanKemplay did you ever figure this out?  I'm getting the same thing on one of my batch jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I had exact same problem. Contacted the salesforce support and they solved the issue. The problem was Batch query for some of the chunks took too long to process. I removed as many fields as I could and it worked. Lowering batc size was also kind of a workaround but not acceptable in my case.

Comment: Thanks for this comment... I had the same issue, and instead of debugging it/ googling it / pulling my hair out, it was a helpful reminder to contact support.